# Как записать в "журнал событий" данные из массива получаемого в событии OnAfterUserAuthorize (1c Bitrix)

Tags: php, битрикс

При авторизации в файле `init.php` вызываю событие `OnAfterUserAuthorize` и записываю данные в логи. Событие отрабатывает корректно, данные в массиве есть но в логи данные из массива не записываются.

```
AddEventHandler("main", "OnAfterUserAuthorize", function(&$fields) {
    $id = $fields['ID'];
        CEventLog::Add(array(
            "DESCRIPTION" => "Пользователь с ID " . $id . " и именем " . $fields['NAME'] . " успешно авторизовался." . $fields['ID'], // получение ID и имени из $fields
        ));
});
```

Соответственно вывод такой - "Пользователь с ID и именем успешно авторизовался."
Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: А данные в `$fields` точно есть?

Comment: @u_mulder, да вывожу через _SESSION, все данные приходят

Comment: И какая связь между сессией и параметром функции. В функции надо делать `var_dump($fields)` и смотреть что пришло.

Comment: @u_mulder, никакой, просто выводил данные на другой странице через _SESSION после обработки события

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по коду функции [CUser::Authorize](https://bxapi.ru/src/?module_id=main&name=CUser::Authorize), в параметры обработчика события OnAfterUserAuthorize передаётся массив

```php
            $arParams = array(
                "user_fields" => $arUser,
                "save" => $bSave,
                "update" => $bUpdate,
                "applicationId" => $applicationId,
            );
```

Соответственно, ваш обработчик должен иметь вид

```php
AddEventHandler("main", "OnAfterUserAuthorize", function(&$fields) {
    $userFields = $fields['user_fields'];
    $id = $userFields ['ID'];
        CEventLog::Add(array(
            "DESCRIPTION" => "Пользователь с ID " . $id . " и именем " . $userFields ['NAME'] . " успешно авторизовался.",
        ));
});
```

Comment: Добавлю, что об этом же (о поле `user_fields`) написано и [в документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/onafteruserauthorize.php), хоть и не в самой, а в комментариях(. Типичная битриксовая дока.